# How to get element of new type in ML?

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

for example if I create a new type

`type map = int * string;`

`val a = (1,"a") : int * string;`

and then I want to get the inner "a" string from variable a, how can I get that?
I have tried a[1], a[2], a(2) and they don't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the new type is just a two-tuple, you may use pattern-matching, just as you would for other types:

```
- val a = (1, "a");
val a = (1,"a") : int * string

- case a of (_, str) => str;
val it = "a" : string

- (fn (_, str) => str) a;
val it = "a" : string
```

If this becomes a common operation, you might consider using a utility function:

```
fun unpackStr (_, str) = str;
```

Comment: thank u so much! but how about the situation that the type is unknown, for example val findElem = (fn (_ , _ ,'a) => 'a); , the third element has an unknown type, and it will have an error 'Error: syntax error: deleting  TYVAR RPAREN DARROW' if I write "val findElem = (fn (_ , _ ,'a) => 'a)"

Comment: `str` is just a variable, it has no special significance. Use any variable name you want, and ML will infer the most-polymorphic type it can.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `#n` operator to get the `n`-th element of any tuple. In the REPL:

```
- #1("one", "two");
val it = "one" : string
- #2("one", "two");
val it = "two" : string
```